# On breakpoint, how can I tell if there's any attached dependency properties for which there's an active value?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, debugging

When looking at a `DependencyObject` instance in the Watch window while the debugger has stopped on a breakpoint, I can see every of its "hard" properties and what values they're on, if any.

This window however - or at least AFAIK -, won't show if there's any attached dependency properties on the object for which a value currently exists (different from "Unset").

Is there any other tool window inside Visual Studio that would give me that information?

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2015 there is a **Live Visual Tree** that you can use to select a UI element and then **Live Property Explorer** will show all attached dependency properties for it.

Comment: +1 for mentionning the Live Property Explorer / Visual Tree, as it might indeed be helpful to somebody else. However in my case I'm afraid that's not good enough. I pretty much always ignore where the object is in the tree, or even if it's present at all.

Comment: Live Property Explorer doesn't show attached properties. Or does it?

Comment: @dotNET Live Property Explorer shows attached properties.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio debugger you can open [WPF Tree Visualizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409789.aspx) for a variable:

[image]

It shows attached property values like Grid.Column set in this example:

[image]